# How to rewrite a decimal number $x$ as $1.y\cdot2^{n}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binary

If I have a number, let's say "$-77,51$", what is a good way to rewrite it as $1.y\cdot 2^{n}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "write it as a product of $2^n$? Do you want it to be written as $x \cdot 2^n$ where $|x|<2$?

Comment: The question does not make sense.

Comment: @kccu Let me clarify. Let's say that I have a number $−77,51$, it can also be written as $−1,21...∗2^6$. What is a good way to write any decimal number in that form?

Comment: @Kevin It is unclear what you mean by "in that form". For instance, if your number is $12$, should I write $1.5 \cdot 2^3$? Or is $3 \cdot 2^2$ acceptable? What about $0.75 \cdot 2^4$? You haven't precisely said what you mean.

Comment: @kccu I'm sorry, you're right. I should've specified. The form is $1.y \cdot 2^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your number $n$, take $\log_2 (|n|)$ and round down to the next smaller integer.  That gives you the power of $2$ you want to have the rest be between $1$ and $2$.  In your example, $\log_2 (77.51)\approx 6.276$ so the exponent is $6$.  Then $2^6=64$, so divide your number by $64$.  $\frac {77.51}{64}\approx 1.2111$

Answer (score 0):

$$x = \frac{x}{\lfloor{\log_2 x}\rfloor}\cdot {\lfloor{\log_2 x}\rfloor},\quad x>0$$